# Integrate qlik sense into my web app

Tags: java, web-applications, integration, qliksense

I'm currently working on a qlik sense app using the desktop edition and what i would like to do is to be able to integrate my qlik app (with all its mashups and extensions) into my web app.

I'm using tomcat for my app .(java)

The process of the integration still a little ambiguous to me. What i understood from what i read in the documentation and other researches that there're 2 ways to do the integration :

```
 - A "free one" : install  the sense desktop edition when my app-server is getting installed, change the path of the sense repositries to where my server is (c:/) and change the settings.ini  with a script; (i don't know if it's a must that the C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\Qlik\Sense stays at where it is or can be removed else where).


 - a "payed one" : using the qlik sense server but i don't know how to let it be in the same domain as my web app just by using a script.
```

I will be very thankful if someone can tell me if both methods are possible and help me get an idea how to deploy them without a need for the customer to step in the process of both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is a java lib that can handle the communication. The official examples are in JS/Nodejs and have seen someone using Python. You need to build your own communication layer using the web sockets API.

Also you can't use the personal edition for this purposes. The PE support only localhost as origin (as far as i know).

QS Server can be used by again you need to find a way to call the api layer from Java.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer . i don't know how to build my own communication layer do u have any links that can help me ? I can use js but i don't know how , can you please give me the link to those examples. how can I know where the user is going to instal the sense server.
Thank you.

Comment: can't i use this : https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/3.1/Subsystems/Installation/Content/InstallationLicensing/Install-Silent.htm and get the "userwithdomain" then some how send it to my app this way i can get the app sheets by config's hostname is the "userwithdomain".  Am i getting that right please tell me what you think ?